# Microsoft Office 365 Desktop Setup Always Shows Up Upon Start Up

Tags: installation, microsoft-office-2013

After I have installed office 365 each time I reboot the computer I have this window that appears:
[image]

Does anyone have an idea about how I can get rid of it?

Thanks for your help.

**Edit:**
Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013, used at work, with office 365 for enterprise subscription.
This is happening only on my computer.  I suspect that somehow, the "first run" flag never gets reset...

Comment: Is this a retail/home copy of Office 365, or does your org use Office 365 cloud services? If the latter - does this happen for all users/computers, or just one?

Comment: Have you uninstalled and reinstalled?

Comment: No, I was hoping I dont have too... I will give it a try and let you know. Thanks for looking at it though!

Comment: I don't have that version of Office to test with, but usually this is controlled by a 'FirstRun' registry setting in HKCU\Software

Comment: You can disable the Microsoft Office while 'Startup' windows on task manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Process Explorer from https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx identified the .exe that was running.

However, it incorrectly reported the registry key and name of the file that's running: HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\Office365DesktopSetup.exe

There was nothing in that registry location for the user I was logged in as, or the administrator account.

2. Searching for Office365DesktopSetup.exe I found the folder location:
   C:\%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\WGD7O2GN.WYM\KMC515ZP.TMP\offi...app_c3bce3770c238a49_0001.0000_c9f9cb17c2686035
3. Searching the registry for WGD7O2GN.WYM lead to the following location:
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
4. Deleting the key refering to the above location removed the prompt.